# XML interpretation issue

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am working using soap, when the soap response is sent back all the < and > are represented using special characters.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <UploadFileNew_XMLResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/GAPS_Uploader/FileUploader">
        <UploadFileNew_XMLResult>
            &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;&lt;Response&gt;&lt;ResCode&gt;1009&lt;/ResCode&gt;&lt;Message&gt;3 transaction(s) failed&lt;/Message&gt;&lt;Errors&gt;&lt;Error&gt;&lt;Rownum&gt;1&lt;/Rownum&gt;&lt;Description&gt;: Reference already exist                                                                                                                                                                               &lt;/Description&gt;&lt;Res_Code&gt;59b1ebbc1c012                                                                                                                                                                                           &lt;/Res_Code&gt;&lt;/Error&gt;&lt;Error&gt;&lt;Rownum&gt;2&lt;/Rownum&gt;&lt;Description&gt;: Reference already exist                                                                                                                                                                               &lt;/Description&gt;&lt;Res_Code&gt;59cb93d6c1d30                                                                                                                                                                                           &lt;/Res_Code&gt;&lt;/Error&gt;&lt;Error&gt;&lt;Rownum&gt;3&lt;/Rownum&gt;&lt;Description&gt;: Reference already exist                                                                                                                                                                               &lt;/Description&gt;&lt;Res_Code&gt;59cbaca456589                                                                                                                                                                                           &lt;/Res_Code&gt;&lt;/Error&gt;&lt;/Errors&gt;&lt;/Response&gt;
        </UploadFileNew_XMLResult>
    </UploadFileNew_XMLResponse>
</soap:Envelope>
```

please how can i simplexml_load_string to process this result.

```
$response = htmlspecialchars_decode($response);
$parser = simplexml_load_string($response);
print_r($parser);
```

Comment: Also add the code which you have tried.

Comment: modified and code i tried included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order:

```
$parser = simplexml_load_string($response);
$response = htmlspecialchars_decode($parser->UploadFileNew_XMLResponse->UploadFileNew_XMLResult);
print_r($response);
```

Comment: `htmlspecialchars_decode` takes a string as the parameter - `simplexml_load_string` returns a SimpleXMLElement.

Comment: @NigelRen Tried but both did not return and xml object.

Comment: @rndus2r This guided me to the right path. After using the
    `$response = htmlspecialchars_decode($parser->UploadFileNew_XMLResponse->UploadFileNew_XMLResult);`
`$parser = simplexml_load_string($response);
print_r($parser);`

worked just fiine.